# Getting a "an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" when page loads but not when it reloads

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

This is for a C# Asp.net Web Forms application that makes an HttpClient PostAsync() call. The first time the page loads I get a "an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" error. Then when I reload the page it doesn't get the error and works. I haven't found any similar cases online. Any idea's on what this could be?

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 { 
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    string sessionId = GetSessionId(client); 
 }
  public static string GetSessionId(HttpClient client)
    {
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "userName", "*******" }, { "password", "********" }, { "orgId", orgId }, { "devKey", devKey } };
        var sessionId = "";
        parameters.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        var encodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);

        var task = Task.Run(() => client.PostAsync(login_uri, encodedContent));

        task.Wait();

        var response = task.Result;

        var content = response.Content;

        var task2 = Task.Run(() => content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        task2.Wait();
        var result = task2.Result;

        var payload = JObject.Parse(result);

        sessionId = payload["response_data"]["sessionId"].ToString(); ;

        return sessionId;
    }
```

Comment: You should provide relevant code to your question. You can see how to ask a good question, here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

An answer to a similar post worked for me. I just added

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```